# Is there an RSS reader for mathematicians?

Tags: soft-question

For a while, I have used Google Reader to stay on top of several math blogs.  Unfortunately, [Google will pull the plug on Reader one month from today](http://googlereader.blogspot.com/), so I need to find an alternative fast.  I was rather pleased with Feedly until I realized it doesn't render $\LaTeX$.  Apparently, [this issue was raised to Feedly](https://feedly.uservoice.com/forums/192636-suggestions/suggestions/3745440-latex-math-support) the day after Google Reader announced its fate, but it hasn't been upvoted very much, so I doubt they will address it anytime soon.

Has anyone found an alternative to Google Reader that is mathematician friendly?

Comment: What do you mean by "does not render LaTeX".  Some examples of sites that break would be helpful.  (From reading the link, it seems like Wordpress blog's like Tao's are an issue.)  I am still using Google Reader (and I need to also look into alternatives).  What shows instead of the math?  Nothing?

Comment: Instead of math, there is nothing - not even a warning that it's ignoring something.  For example, if the entry says "Let $a$ denote..." then Feedly gives you "Let denote...".  Examples of broken sites include Azimuth, Godel's Lost Letter, Normal Deviate, and What's new.

Comment: Just upvoted on Feedly.  Maybe that's the best thing to do for now.

Comment: You can try if robjohn's (a moderator on math.stackexchange.com) "render MathJax" bookmarklet helps http://www.math.ucla.edu/~robjohn/math/mathjax.html On any page containing LaTeX (for example arXiv abstracts) it will render the formulas with a single click.

Comment: @Martin: It doesn't work.  It appears as though "render MathJax" works on arXiv abstracts because it sees LaTeX between dollar signs and replaces it with beautiful math.  Unfortunately, Feedly gives you nothing (not even the LaTeX code in dollar signs), so "render MathJax" has nothing to work with.

Comment: Have you tried The Old Reader already? It can be found at theoldreader.com and I am quite happy with it.

Comment: @Gregor, since you are already on The Old Reader, let us know if it shows LaTeX correctly.  For example, look at What's New (terrytao.wordpress.com), or any Wordpress.com blog for that matter with LaTeX in it.  (I assume like Google Reader you can add a feed and then remove it easily.)

Comment: @Jason: LaTeX seems to work with The Old Reader. That was actually my reason for suggesting it. I probably should have been clearer.

Answer (score 6):

Following Gregor Samsa's recommendation in the comments, I decided to try The Old Reader.  (I hadn't tried it before because the site warns that it's only in beta mode, and I want a reliable RSS reader.)  The interface is very familiar (coming from Google Reader), and unlike Feedly, The Old Reader actually renders LaTeX (e.g., for all Wordpress blogs).  If Feedly addresses the LaTeX issue, I might switch back (since Feedly is not in beta, and arguably more reliable), but until then, The Old Reader might be the best alternative.

Answer (score 5):

With Christian Perfect's [MathJax Bookmarklet](http://checkmyworking.com/misc/mathjax-bookmarklet/), you can render $\LaTeX$ math just about anywhere on the web! It works fine with the old Google Reader, Feedly, and probably all the main web based RSS readers out there.

Comment: I don’t care about RSS readers, but the bookmarklet is just awesome.

Answer (score 1):

an email-based alternative to Google Reader that some are quite happy with, and which renders LaTeX, is Blogtrottr ---

http://robert.orzanna.de/2013/04/google-reader-shutdown-blogtrottr-being.html

Here's how a typical Blogtrottr output looks like in a mail client (Thunderbird):

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I've now downloaded TheOld Reader but since my old reader disappeared, I can't import my old feeds. What are the names the old reader will recognize for mathoverflow, n-forum, n-lab

Answer (score 1):

Feedbro Feed Reader (for Chrome) supports MathJax (just enable MathJax support in Options). See http://nodetics.com/feedbro